# Can Raspberry Pi 4 learn to fly an model aircraft and is it the correct board?

Tags: dc-motor

So I have not yet bought a Raspberry Pi, but I just want to know if I have chosen the correct development board that will help to make a model airplane that flies by itself. I know this is too much, but I am planning to make it. So, I have listed out all the stuff I might need to make this aircraft. I want Raspberry Pi to learn how to fly a plane. Thats my first goal.

Thanks, Paarth

Comment: Keep in mind the "standard" (raspberry pi OS) linux doesn't use a real-time kernel so there are no guarantees about latency before some critical part of your control software gets run. ie. you plane might not perform the way you want while the kernel is off doing something else. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241264/what-makes-a-kernel-os-real-time).

Answer (score 3):

Just trying to understand exactly what you're asking here:

If you're querying if the pi can power the dc motor(s) you'll need some extra hardware usually with seperate power supply (like a motor HAT or a motor driver IC - see https://www.electronicshub.org/controlling-a-dc-motor-with-raspberry-pi/ ) as the raspberry pi alone cannot supply the current required to get the motor running initially.

If you're querying the programming capabilities of the raspberry pi, you should be just fine - a raspberry pi 4 has been more than enough for all projects I've undertaken when it comes to the processor.

Good luck with your project :)

Comment: Sure, I have the the ESCs and Brushless motors and I have seen a few video about connecting an ESC to Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I am on the right track!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the Raspberry Pi itself is not able to fly a plane. As Ben stated, you could use a HAT to get motor controls or using the [PWM output to drive an ESC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yum1ilAGT4Y&ab_channel=DanielBrown). You could connect a GPS to the UART and get the exact position to steer the plane. But there is one problem, you have to program everything by yourself, as there aren't any softwares known to me, that enable the Pi to auto pilot your plane.

I think what you're looking forward to is a [Pixhawk](https://pixhawk.org/) or an [Ardupilot](https://ardupilot.org/). The last one is cheaply available through chinese sellers. There you can connect out of the box a GPS, program failsafe and do way more features.

Good luck from me aswell :)

Comment: So, if I learn Raspberry Pi, then can I program, I mean, is it possible?? And I checked out Ardupilot, but didn't understand much

Comment: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/10/02/deep-learning-on-the-raspberry-pi-with-opencv/ Is this related to my project??

Comment: Almost everything is possible, but please take a look in the [BetaFlight Repository](https://github.com/betaflight/betaflight). The task of making a plane fly by itself and itself being aware of its location and steering takes a lot of skill you have to aquire. You should "learn the Raspberry Pi" but you also should learn to program, communication protocols etc. ArduPilot is basically a custom Arduino Board, which is a Flight Controller. You can Install a software like BetaFlight on it and setup a GPS antenna.

Comment: Hi Marvin, Here's a list of stuff that I am going to buy:
Needed for Project
Brushless Motor
ESC 
LiPo Battery pack
Charger
GPS Module
Heatsink and Cooling Fans
Cost = Rs. 7000 
And with Raspberry Pi: Rs. 11,500

I have and are needed
Voltage Sensor
Gyroscope 
Servos (I need more)

Comment: Am I missing out something, or is this enough?

Comment: Sounds good, but I doubt you need a voltage sensor, as long as you don't want to send telemetry. An estimate about power draw and Lipo size should be enough.

Comment: You should also take spare parts in mind, as programming or engineering errors can destroy the Raspberry Pi and other electrical components.

Comment: Ok Sure Thanks Marvin, I think I'll be using it cause, I already have it. I have another question. I want to train Raspberry Pi to fly a plane in a simulator first, so that it makes a better neural network, and at last when its done, i want to implement it into the model plane

Comment: Iam sorry, I don't understand the question here.

Comment: Paarth, please use google.

Comment: I mean to say, before letting it fly a model plane, it should perform well in a simulator, So that it doesn't break the model plane

Comment: And Marvin, do I need a camera?

Comment: As far as i can tell, this article could sort of assist with what you're trying to do in terms of the simulating. But adding turning would massively increase the difficulty as far as i know (with my limited physics knowledge). https://towardsdatascience.com/how-i-taught-a-plane-to-fly-using-rl-c170a152b771 https://towardsdatascience.com/ai-learns-to-fly-part-2-create-your-custom-rl-environment-and-train-an-agent-b56bbd334c76

Comment: But not sure if you actually need a neural network to control the plane as surely just a few conditions such as height (with a distance sensor) etc could just be connected to an if statement?

Comment: E.g. `if (Height going down)and(taking off) then(GoUp)`